# Semantics of comparison of char objects

Tags: c++, character-encoding, char

While I was reading through some old code today, I noticed the following `assert` line:

```
assert(('0' <= hexChar && hexChar <= '9')
    || ('A' <= hexChar && hexChar <= 'F')
    || ('a' <= hexChar && hexChar <= 'f'));
```

The purpose is to assert that `hexChar` is a hexadecimal digit ([0-9A-Fa-f]). It does this by relying on an ASCII-like ordering of `char` objects representing `'A'`, `'B'`, ..., `'F'` and `'a'`, `'b'`, ..., `'f'`.

I began wondering whether this always does what I intended, given that the execution character set is implementation-defined.

The C++ standard in Section 2.3, Character sets, mentions:

> The *basic execution character set* and the *basic execution wide-character set* shall each contain all the members of the basic source character set, plus control characters representing alert, backspace, and carriage return, plus a *null character* (respectively, *null wide character*), whose representation has all zero bits. For each basic execution character set, the values of the members shall be non-negative and distinct from one another. In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous. The *execution character set* and the *execution wide-character set* are implementation-defined supersets of the basic execution character set and the basic execution wide-character set, respectively. The values of the members of the execution character sets and the sets of additional members are locale-specific.

I interpret this to mean that `('0' <= hexChar && hexChar <= '9')` is okay because `'0'`, `'1'`, ..., `'9'` are digits and each has a value one greater than the previous. However, the order of other basic source characters with respect to one another is still implementation-defined.

Is this a correct statement? Knowing nothing about the C++ compiler (so not knowing the implementation details), do I need to rewrite the `assert` as the following?

```
assert(('0' <= hexChar && hexChar <= '9')
    || ('A' == hexChar || 'B' == hexChar || 'C' == hexChar || 'D' == hexChar || 'E' == hexChar || 'F' == hexChar)
    || ('a' == hexChar || 'b' == hexChar || 'c' == hexChar || 'd' == hexChar || 'e' == hexChar || 'f' == hexChar));
```

Comment: I removed the C tag, as you quoted the C++ Standard.

Comment: `[0-9A-Za-z]` are [sexatrigesimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36) digits, not hexadecimal.

Comment: @Ben: Thanks for pointing this out. I corrected the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first line, comparison against the values of `'0'` and `'9'` is 100% portable. It's guaranteed by the C language to behave identically for all implementations.

The second and third lines are in principle implementation-defined, but there has never been, and never will be, an implementation where their behavior differs. The only non-ISO646-compatible character encoding that has ever been used with the C language (and the only reason C allows non-ISO646-compatible encodings) is EBCDIC, which places the letters `'A'` through `'F'` exactly where they should fall as hexadecimal values (in general the letters are discontiguous in EBCDIC, but A-F are one contiguous group).

With that said, unless you need to support legacy mainframes, there is no value in trying to handle basic character encoding "portably" in C. `char` is 8 bits, the values 0-127 are ASCII, and the values 128-255 are part of a locale- or data-specific multibyte character encoding which we'll someday be able to assume is always UTF-8.

Comment: "char is 8 bits". I think it's marginally worthwhile not assuming this part, as long as that won't ruin your day. Probably text-handling code won't be useful on a DSP, but you never know.

Comment: Well the useful value space is 8 bits, and if it's more than 8 bits, you're going to have a hard time finding any remotely portable way for the program to communicate with the outside world, so I don't see any value for "portability" with such implementations.

Comment: @R..: What I mean is, don't rely on `CHAR_BIT == 8` exactly, unless there's an actual benefit to doing so beyond the usual, "`8` is fewer characters and my fingers are tired". If I'm writing a routine/library to parse some text format that involves hex characters, and therefore I'm doing this test, it doesn't necessarily follow that my code has to communicate with the outside world. It's my caller's problem where the string comes from. It's unlikely but not impossible that someone could be doing something unusual on a DSP (or a massive rack of DSPs) and benefit from using my code.

Comment: POSIX requires `CHAR_BIT == 8`.  As does Windows.

Comment: @dan04: right, so none of those DSPs with memory that's only addressable to a resolution of 16 or 32 bits will be running Windows or implementing Posix, at least not without some scary emulation/indirection. But they can run C++, and my point is that this is real hardware and real compilers that actually exist, not like the hypothetical non-ASCII, non-EBCDIC basic character sets that R.. dismisses. So assuming `CHAR_BIT == 8` is an extra step, and I think it's rarely all that useful when handling text in the basic character set, so shouldn't be introduced for weak reasons.

Comment: I agree there's no reason to senselessly impose `CHAR_BIT==8`, but I'm also not going to go out of my way and clutter code if supporting `CHAR_BIT!=8` would require extra special casing. I might add `assert(SCHAR_MIN==-128)` just to help document the requirements (8-bit, twos-complement) when I write code that depends on it, to make porting easier if somebody ever needs to port it to weird systems.

Answer (score 5):

To your first question: yes.

To your second question: perhaps, but probably you should consider using the C library `isxdigit` function or a C++ locale variant of this.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, it's entirely legal for a C++ compiler to use some other character encoding. However, the reality is that you almost certainly won't find a platform where this code doesn't work. This is especially true since the new dominant character encodings are Unicode-based, like UTF-16, and Unicode shares all the ASCII values for all characters in the ASCII set. The only reason this is implementation-defined is for very, very old legacy platforms that still existed when this part of the Standard was written- and you'd have to substantially refactor your code to run on any platform that is non-ASCII.